# SonarQube - Kubernetes - LDAP - Not using sonar.properties file?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, kubernetes

This is NOT a question on how to get information to set up LDAP. This is about a specific config and issues.

Config:
SonarQube: Latest running in a Tectonic Kube Cluster.
Database: Postgres:latest running also in a Kube Cluster.

Issue:
I put my LDAP configuration into the $SONAR_HOME/config/sonar.properties file and it's not being picked up.

Questions:

- What I find interesting is that every line in that file is commented
  out, so is the server REALLY using this file or is it somewhere else?
- If it is somewhere else, where?
- Will changes survive a pod restart?
- If not, how to make the changes "stick"?

Thanks all as always and let me know if I can add more information or details.

Comment: It will help to include the docker image you are using to run Sonar, as those vary wildly about any env-vars they honor, config locations, etc

Comment: I am just pulling SonarQube:Latest from the public Repo.

https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my case, I am running SonarQube in Kubernetes. We're using TECTONIC to manage our environment.

What I ended up needing to do is make the changes to the $SONAR_HOME/config/sonar.properties file, but not directly into the server.

I ended up needing to create a new Manifest File (.yaml) to store the configuration file into a Secret Store (encrypt the properties file with base64) and the apply it as a secret.

I will have full documentation and supporting documentation on my repo soon, but I wanted to come back and close this loop.

(https://github.com/Talderon/k8s-sonarqube-golang)

Comment: Hi, I am running into the same problem. I have to bind my sonarqube to 0.0.0.0 and set that in my sonar.properties file. I have written a yaml for deployment but I am not sure how I am going to add properties to my sonar.properties file. Your shared link is not available anymore. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Here is where I have asked the question if you can look into it once!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184344/sonar-cannot-be-access-via-istio-virtual-service-but-can-be-locally-accessed-aft