# Sonar cannot be access via istio virtual service but can be locally accessed after port forwarding

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, sonarqube, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to implement SonarQube in a Kubernetes cluster. The deployment is running properly and is also exposed via a Virtual Service. I am able to open the UI via the `localhost:port/sonar` but I am not able to access it through my external ip. I understand that sonar binds to localhost and does not allow access from outside the remote server. I am running this on GKE with a MYSQL database. Here is my YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonar
  labels:
    service: sonarqube
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sonarqube
      labels:
        name: sonarqube
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 15
      initContainers:
        - name: volume-permission
          image: busybox
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          image: sonarqube:6.7
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 4Gi
              cpu: 2
            requests:
              memory: 2Gi
              cpu: 1
          args:
            - -Dsonar.web.context=/sonar
            - -Dsonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
          env:
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: password
            - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
              value: jdbc:mysql://***.***.**.*:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              name: sonarqube-port
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: sonarqube
    version: v1
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonar
spec:
  selector:
    name: sonarqube
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: sonarqube-port
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-internal
  namespace: sonar
spec:
  hosts:
    - sonarqube.staging.jeet11.internal
    - sonarqube
  gateways:
    - default/ilb-gateway
    - mesh
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: sonarqube
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-external
  namespace: sonar
spec:
  hosts:
    - sonarqube.staging.jeet11.com
  gateways:
    - default/elb-gateway
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: sonarqube
---
```

The deployment completes successfully. My exposed services gives a public ip that has been mapped to the host url but I am unable to access the service at the host url.

I need to change the mapping such that sonar binds with the server ip but I am unable to understand how to do that. I cannot bind it to my cluster ip, neither to my internal or external service ip.

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: Hi, what version of kubernetes and istio do You use? Do You have any other deployment that works with istio?

Comment: My kubectl versions are: Client Version: v1.16.3; Server Version: v1.13.11-gke.14
I am not sure about my istio version. Yes all my other deployments are running through the istio gateway as a virtual service. This is the only service that is giving me a problem.

Comment: Istio version is 1.3.3

Comment: I deployed it using helm and that worked via a normal LoadBalancer. I wasn't able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue recently and I managed to get this resolved today.

I hope the following solution will work for anyone facing the same issue!.

## Environment

- Cloud Provider: **Azure - AKS**

  - This should work regardless of whatever provider you use.
- Istio Version: 1.7.3
- K8 Version: 1.16.10

## Tools - Debugging

- `kubectl logs -n istio-system -l app=istiod`

  - logs from Istiod and events happening in the control plane.
- `istioctl analyze -n <namespace>`

  - This generally gives you any warnings and errors for a given namespace.
  - Lets you know if things are misconfigured.
- Kiali - `istioctl dashboard kiali`

  - See if you are getting inbound traffic.
  - Also, shows you any misconfigurations.
- Prometheus - `istioctl dashboard prometheus`

  - query metric - `istio_requests_total`. This shows you the traffic going into the service.
  - If there's any misconfiguration you will see the **destination_app** as **unknown**.

## Issue

- Unable to access sonarqube UI via external IP, but accessible via localhost (port-forward).
- Unable to route traffic via Istio Ingressgateway.

## Solution

#### Sonarqube Service Manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonarqube
  labels:
    name: sonarqube
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: sonarqube
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

- Your **targetport** is the container port. To avoid any confusion just assign the service **port** number as same as the service **targetport**.
- The port name is very important here. “Istio required the service ports to follow the naming form of ‘protocol-suffix’ where the ‘-suffix’ part is optional” - [KIA0601 - Port name must follow [-suffix] form](https://kiali.io/documentation/v1.15/validations/#_kia0601_port_name_must_follow_protocol_suffix_form)

#### Istio Gateway and VirtualService manifest for sonarqube

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-gateway
  namespace: sonarqube
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 9000
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "XXXX.XXXX.com.au"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: sonarqube
spec:
  hosts:
  - "XXXX.XXXX.com.au"
  gateways:
  - sonarqube-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: sonarqube
        port:
          number: 9000
```

- Gateway protocol must be set to **HTTP**.
- **Gateway Server Port** and **VirtualService Destination Port** is the same. If you have different app **Service Port**, then your **VirtualService Destination Port** number should match the app **Service Port**. The **Gateway Server Port** should match the app **Service Targetport**.
- Now comes to the fun bit! The **hosts**. If you want to access the service outside of the cluster, then you need to have your host-name (whatever host-name that you want to map the sonarqube server) as an **DNS A record** mapped to the External Public IP address of the **istio-ingressgateway**.
- To get the **EXTERNAL-IP** address of the ingressgateway, run `kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway`.
- If you do a simple nslookup (run - `nslookup <hostname>`), The IP address you get must match with the IP address that is assigned to the istio-ingressgateway service.

#### Expose a new port in the ingressgateway

- Note that your sonarqube gateway port is a new port that you are introducing to Kubernetes and you’re telling the cluster to listen on that port. But your load balancer doesn’t know about this port. Therefore, **you need to open the specified gateway port on your kubernetes external load balancer**. Ref - [Info](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7242#issuecomment-406808437)
- You don’t need to manually change your load balancer service. You just need to update the ingress gateway to include the new port, which will update the load balancer automatically.
- You can identify if the port is causing issues by running `istioctl analyze -n sonarqube`. You should get the following warning;

`[33mWarn[0m [IST0104] (Gateway sonarqube-gateway.sonarqube) The gateway refers to a port that is not exposed on the workload (pod selector istio=ingressgateway; port 9000) Error: Analyzers found issues when analyzing namespace: sonarqube. See https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/analysis for more information about causes and resolutions.`

- You should get the corresponding error in the control plane. Run `kubectl logs -n istio-system -l app=istiod`.
- At this point **you need to update the Istio ingressgateway service to expose the new port**. Run `kubectl edit svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system` and add the following section to the ports.

[image]

#### Bypass creating a new port

- In the previous section you saw how to expose a new port. This is optional and depending on your use case.
- In this section you will see how to use a port that is already exposed.
- If you look at the service of the istio-ingressgateway. You can see that there are default ports exposed. Here we are going to use port 80.

[image]

- Your setup will look like the following;
  [image]

[image]

- To void specifying the port with your host name just add match uri prefix, as shown in the virtualservice manifest.

#### Time for testing

- If everything works up to this point as expected, then you are good to go.

[image]

- During testing I made one mistake by not specifying the port. If you get 404 status, Which is still a good thing, in this way you can verify what server it is using. If you setup things correctly, it should use the **istio-envoy** server, not the **nginx**.

[image]

- Without specifiying the port. This will only work if you add the match uri prefix.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I will try it out, I am running SonarQube in a remote server right now, this solution would be super helpful to keep everything in kube.

Comment: Yeah it would be, k8 all the way. I have updated the answer. You'll find the new update easier to implement :).

Answer (score 0):

Donot pass argument just try running without it once working for me.

This is how my deployment file hope helpful

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: sonarqube
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
  name: sonarqube
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          image: sonarqube:7.1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1200Mi"
              cpu: .10
            limits:
              memory: "2500Mi"
              cpu: .50
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/data/"
            name: sonar-data
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/extensions/"
            name: sonar-extensions
          env:
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME"
            value: "root"  #Put your db username
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL"
            value: "jdbc:mysql://192.168.112.4:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true" #DB URL
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD"
            value : password
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: sonar-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonar-data
      - name: sonar-extensions
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonar-extensions
```

Comment: Are you using a private ip for your mysql or are you using a public ip?

Comment: Thanks but this is not working for me. I can still access the UI via port-forward from localhost to the pod but not able to use it via the virtual service.

Comment: i am using private ip for mysql and using ingress to access.